# Is it safe to delete auto extracted old version graphics card drivers?

Tags: drivers, graphics-card

[image]

Just wanting to clean up a bit. Is it safe to delete these folders or do the graphics cards still use stuff from the old ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as I know this folders was automatically extracted by Nvidia installer. You can delete this folders. Actual driver files is usually stored in \System32\Drivers

Answer (score 2):

You can delete INTEL NVIDIA and ATI folders in root without any problem.